# combining two consecutive rows using

Tags: python

I have the following input file:

```
1   1
10  2666
11  3102
12  2854
13  2617
14  2640
```

I want output like:

```
1-10    2667
10-11   5768
11-12   5956
12-13   5471
13-14   5257
```

Please help me how to do so. 
I tried using a for loop. But I am getting `single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` error.

Code:

```
lst = []
insert_at = 1

for i in t.index:
    z = (t['hrs'].iloc[i]) + "-" + (t['hrs'].iloc[i+1])
    print(z)
    lst.insert(1,z)
```

Error: `IndexError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-b8c99d9e7ee1> in <module>
      3 
      4 for i in t.index:
----> 5     z = (t['hrs'].iloc[i]) + "-" + (t['hrs'].iloc[i+1])
      6     print(z)
      7     lst.insert(1,z)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1422 
   1423             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1424             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1425 
   1426     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   2155 
   2156             # validate the location
-> 2157             self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   2158 
   2159             return self._get_loc(key, axis=axis)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   2086         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2087         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2088             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2089 
   2090     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Comment: I don't see any question.

Comment: i have updated the question, please check.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you add the code and the full stacktrace of the error you're getting?

Comment: updated. please check.

Comment: Are you starting from a Dataframe or is Pandas just something you're trying on a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as the stacktrace is telling you, is that you are going out of bound of your dataframe.

```
(t['hrs'].iloc[i+1])
```

There are 6 rows and you are iterating through each of them. What happens when you hit the last row, aka `i+1=6`? It doesn't exist.

Instead what you can do is to create a column but with all the values shifted up by 1.

```
t['next_hrs'] = t['hrs'].shift(-1)
t['z'] = (t['hrs']) + "-" + (t['next_hrs'])
```